# I have a large hql query and I am calling it using pyspark sql . But I am getting error like Bad connect ack with firstBadLink error

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I know this may have been asked before also but I am asking it because I am not sure whether the issue is same or not.
The thing is that I am using a spark-sql and I am first creating a table like :

```py
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

sqlContext.sql("""drop table if exists test_table""")

sqlContext.sql(""" create external table test_table
.
.
.
.
.
.)
partitioned by('column_name' datatype)
stored as textfile 
location '/home/..../test_table' 
""")
```

> This table has like 400-500 columns or even more than that

Then , I am insert overwriting from getting data from multiple huge  huge tables using union all like

```
sqlContext.sql("""
    insert overwrite table table_name
    partition(`column_name`) 
select
col1,
col2,
col3,
..
..
from table1
left join ... table2 on ...
left join ... table3
left join ... tale_4
union all
select col1,
col2,
..
..
..
from table5
left join.. ... table6

.
.
.
.union all



from table19
left join tabl18 ... 
""")
```

Kindly advise.

### EDIT

>

```
18/09/26 22:18:57 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 590.9 in stage 67.0 (TID 25051) on #####, executor 3: java.io.IOException (Bad connect ack with firstBadLink as *****:1004) [duplicate 15]
18/09/26 22:18:57 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 590.10 in stage 67.0 (TID 25161, *.com, executor 3, partition 590,NODE_LOCAL, 2348 bytes)
18/09/26 22:18:57 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 531.10 in stage 67.0 (TID 25162, *.com, executor 13, partition 531,NODE_LOCAL, 2348 bytes)
18/09/26 22:18:57 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 431.8 in stage 67.0 (TID 25066) on ***, executor 13: java.io.IOException (Bad connect ack with firstBadLink as *******:1004) [duplicate 25]
18/09/26 22:18:57 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 431.9 in stage 67.0 (TID 25163, ****, executor 13, partition 431,NODE_LOCAL, 2348 bytes)
18/09/26 22:18:57 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 443.9 in stage 67.0 (TID 25076) on ****, executor 13: java.io.IOException (Bad connect ack with firstBadLink as *****:1004) [duplicate 24]
18/09/26 22:18:57 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 774.9 in stage 67.0 (TID 25058) on ****, executor 3: java.io.IOException (Bad connect ack with firstBadLink as *****:1004) [duplicate 9]
18/09/26 22:18:57 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 774.10 in stage 67.0 (TID 25164, ****, executor 15, partition 774,NODE_LOCAL, 2348 bytes)
18/09/26 22:18:57 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 790.9 in stage 67.0 (TID 25053) on ****, executor 3: java.io.IOException (Bad connect ack with firstBadLink as ******:1004) [duplicate 16]
18/09/26 22:18:57 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 790.10 in stage 67.0 (TID 25165, ****, executor 15, partition 790,NODE_LOCAL, 2348 bytes)
18/09/26 22:18:57 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 574.9 in stage 67.0 (TID 25061) on ****, executor 15: java.io.IOException (Bad connect ack with firstBadLink as *****:1004) [duplicate 17]
18/09/26 22:18:57 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 574.10 in stage 67.0 (TID 25166, ****, executor 3, partition 574,NODE_LOCAL, 2348 bytes)
18/09/26 22:18:57 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 433.9 in stage 67.0 (TID 25167, ****, executor 14, partition 433,NODE_LOCAL, 2348 bytes)
18/09/26 22:18:57 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 419.9 in stage 67.0 (TID 25075) on ****, executor 14: java.io.IOException (Bad connect ack with firstBadLink as *****:1004) [duplicate 26]
18/09/26 22:18:57 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 474.9 in stage 67.0 (TID 25054) on ****, executor 15: java.io.IOException (Bad connect ack with firstBadLink as ****:1004) [duplicate 10]
18/09/26 22:18:57 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 474.10 in stage 67.0 (TID 25168, ****, executor 3, partition 474,NODE_LOCAL, 2348 bytes)
18/09/26 22:18:57 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 436.10 in stage 67.0 (TID 25169, ****, executor 19, partition 436,NODE_LOCAL, 2348 bytes)
18/09/26 22:18:57 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 411.8 in stage 67.0 (TID 25056, ****, executor 19): java.io.IOException: Bad connect ack with firstBadLink as ****:1004
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1643)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1541)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:683)
```

> ---

```
File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.9.0-1.cdh5.9.0.p0.23/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 580, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._ssql_ctx.sql(sqlQuery), self)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.9.0-1.cdh5.9.0.p0.23/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.9.0-1.cdh5.9.0.p0.23/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 45, in deco
18/09/26 22:19:09 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 1210.4 in stage 67.0 (TID 25307, ****.com, executor 8): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.9.0-1.cdh5.9.0.p0.23/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
18/09/26 22:19:09 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 449.12 in stage 67.0 (TID 25300, ***.com, executor 14): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o61.sql.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 403 in stage 67.0 failed 14 times, most recent failure: Lost task 403.13 in stage 67.0 (TID 25227, *******, executor 7): java.io.IOException: Bad connect ack with firstBadLink as ******:1004
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1643)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1541)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:683)

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1642)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1601)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1590)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1844)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1857)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1934)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.saveAsHiveFile(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:84)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:201)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.sideEffectResult(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.doExecute(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:276)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:55)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:55)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:145)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$.apply(DataFrame.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:817)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Bad connect ack with firstBadLink as ******:1004
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1643)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1541)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:683)
```

Comment: can you put error stacktrace.

Comment: @GaurangShah I have added the error . It keeps on displaying the same thing on repeat untill the program terminates.

Comment: Maybe a firewall rule is blocking your connection?

Comment: @pri is thery any way to be sure of that . Becuase if that is the problem then I need to take help of admin team. And for that I have to be sure of that .

Comment: What server is `******` ? Is it a node in cluster? Something else?

Comment: @pri yes . It is a node in cluster

Comment: Maybe you could take help of your admin team to check if the port 1004 is open on that node in the cluster. I'm sorry but I don't know the way to check if a port is open on a node.

Comment: @pri sure , and if you can think any other reason that may be causing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're writing large data, the file where you are storing on your data must be compressed. that means you have to use *Parquet* instead of *Textfile*.
I had the same error and I resolved it by using **Parquet** as below:

```
...
partitioned by('column_name' datatype)
stored as parquet
location '/home/..../test_table'
...
```

Just try it!

Answer (score 1):

By seeing the logs, it has nothing to deal with query issue. This bad **Bad connect ack with firstBadLink error** means while processing query problem while getting required data for processing, seems like the data nodes / input data in consistent states, try to check if there is any outage in your cluster due to which data node service is not running correctly. Try to restart data node service if that is the case.

Or may issue with your firewall which blocking data, you may try to disable firewall and try to do execution.